# semi-frequent reboots on Galaxy tab; ways to troubleshoot?

Tags: reboot, android-11, troubleshooting, twitter

I have a Galaxy Tab S6 Lite, Android 11, which I generally love. I have a SD card connected to it. It's 2 years old. Storage-wise, I have tons of space, especially on the SD card.

I an experiencing semi-frequent reboots. Today, in fact, it rebooted on 3 separate occasions -- a little unusual for me.

I'm good at troubleshooting desktop apps, but not so much with android stuff. Is there a process to follow? Where to go to get good info? Are there any utilities to use to help troubleshoot? I haven't found much useful information under Settings.

Today I was using the Twitter app before all 3 reboots, and for the third reboot, the only app I was running was Twitter, which seems like a dead giveaway. But how can I confirm this?  I'm not convinced that Twitter is the only cause, but have no idea how to check.

It wouldn't surprise me if the Twitter app was causing problems. It connects to and launches other apps within it (news app, etc). And there are some complaints at the Google Play store. But I really feel I don't understand how to track and resolve problems like this. Any help is appreciated.

Under the Settings --> Apps --> Twitter, I see that average memory usage is 4.2 MB, and that maximum memory usage is 268MB which does not seem excessive to me.

Final question. If one app is causing reboots, is deleting and installing fresh likely to help?

Comment: On Android apps should not be able to cause a reboot theoretically. Usually frequent reboots can be caused by a bad battery but your tablet is less than two years old so this is unlikely unless you caused the damage yourself (overheating by sun, freezing, use the phone until it goes off because of draining battery). Other options are difficult to test unless you identified a way to trigger such a reboot.